# Audit Records queried from SQL Server 2008 (Database and Analysis Services)

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server

I'm preparing a clinical data warehouse and I need to be able to audit the specific records that users query from either the relational database or the analysis services cubes.  The key requirements is that I need the ability to ascertain any specific patients that are viewed by any users.  Since it's an OLAP database, users can view pull-up whatever data they wish in an ad-hoc manner through the BI tool.

The current plan is to not make private health data query-able through the warehouse and give them a seperate application when they need to see specific patients, this app would do the auditing.  I'd like make everything query-able if possible, so if anyone has a pattern or product that can help out I'd be interested to hear about it.

Answer (score 1):

you can use sqlserver audit to log the sql statements, not the actual records. If you make sure that bind variables are not used, the actual sql including filter and join predicates will be logged. That is for the database

For the cubes, you can enable tracing. Google it for better info on this part